# how to iterate dictionary combined with another list

Tags: python

MRE:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3}
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
```

iterate dictionary key-value pairs by using:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
>>> a 1
>>> b 2
>>> c 3
```

However I want to combine it with colors list. 
This is what I desire:

```
for (key, value, color) in (d.items(), colors):
    print(key, value, color)
>>> a 1 red
>>> b 2 green
>>> c 3 blue
```

How can I achieve this?

right now I am changing key, value into lists and then iterate through 3 lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate over more than one element at the same time like this:

```py
d = {"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3}
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]


for (key, value), color in zip(d.items(), colors):
    print(key, value, color)

>>> a 1 red
>>> b 2 green
>>> c 3 blue
```

Comment: Ah adding ( ) brackets fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: Adding warning from my deleted (as it was a strict duplicate otherwise) answer: Note that the ordering of `dict`s is unspecified (and for `str` keys, unstable even on the same interpreter from run to run) prior to Python 3.6, so the match up between the `dict` and the `colors` will not be useful before then (the `dict` will iterate in a roughly random order). From 3.6 on (though only a language guarantee in 3.7+) insertion ordering is guaranteed, so you'll get predictable results.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that is true! Even in `python 3.6` is only available in the `CPython` implementation, the official ordering is only guaranteed in `python 3.7+`.

Comment: @Marcos: It's available on PyPy 3.6 too (because PyPy is the one that invented the technique and implemented it first, I think in 3.5). Conveniently, no other alternate interpreter has even been released with 3.6 support, so all existing 3.6+ interpreters do support it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `zip`, can you try the following:

```
for dd, cc in zip(d, colors):
    print(dd, d[dd], cc)
```

Comment: Why not iterate `items` and unpack them too, saving a second round of lookup?